# how to select a bunch of objects automatically in ssma(SQL Server Migration Assistant)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, automation, sql-server-migration-assi

I'm using ssma to migrate from oracle to SQL Server with about 1000 tables.

And during the migration, about 100 tables went wrong (because of wrong type mapping) and I want to rerun only those tables.

Are there any way to select them automatically(by script or even some third-party tools) rather than click them one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question..

Turns out ssma has a built in function called "Advanced Object Selection" in the right click menu.
[Advanced Object Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmyJo.png)

And then you can input tables(or other object names) in the "Set Selection".
[Set Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tVtO.png)